# asp.net | Data transfer from the Db by the Controller to the View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

**Desc:**

- I get information from a database using EF

```
var card= _ecpContext.Card.Where(sth).ToList();
```

- this gives me information in the List <> format

  > card Count = 31
  >
  > [0] {App.Models.Card}
  >
  > [1] {App.Models.Card}
  >
  > [2] {App.Models.Card}
- I want to transfer this data from controller to view
- I am trying to do it like this:

***Controller:***

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> MethodsReturnView(string previously_uploaded_data_from_ajax)
{

var userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var userDetailsAU = _ecpContext.AC_Merge_V.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ADlogin == userName);
            var userDetails = _context.Uzytkownicy.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Adlogin == userName);

            dynamic serializer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary>(previously_uploaded_data_from_ajax);

            var numerMiesiacaObject = serializer["numerMiesiaca"];
            var numerRokuObject = serializer["numerRoku"];
            var liczbaDniObject = serializer["liczbaDni"];


            int numerMiesiaca = Convert.ToInt32(numerMiesiacaObject);
            int numerRoku = Convert.ToInt32(numerRokuObject);
            int liczbaDni = Convert.ToInt32(liczbaDniObject);


            ViewBag.numerMiesiaca = numerMiesiaca;
            ViewBag.numerRoku = numerRoku;
            ViewBag.liczbadni = liczbaDni;


      var dbExists = _ecpContext.Karta.FirstOrDefault(f => f.DzMiesiaca == 1 && f.Miesiac == numerMiesiaca && f.Rok == numerRoku && f.Login == userName);
            if (dbExists == null)
            {
                List<Karta_Model> objKartaModel = new List<Karta_Model>();

                for (int i = 1; i <= liczbaDni; i++)
                {

                    var model = new Karta_Model()
                    {
                      // sth
                    };

                    objKartaModel.Add(model);

                }



                await _ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objKartaModel);
                await _ecpContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            var karta = _ecpContext.Karta.Where(f => f.Miesiac == numerMiesiaca && f.Rok == numerRoku && f.Login == userName).OrderBy(x => x.Rok).ThenBy(x => x.Miesiac).ThenBy(x => x.DzMiesiaca).ToList();


     return PartialView("_ReturnView", karta);
}
```

**Problem:**

- but it throws me an error if it adds 'card' near the returned view

  > Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
- the error is thrown when the return command is invoked (investigated, red dot)
- without sending this data, the view returns normally

**Additionally:**

***My model:***

```
public partial class Karta_Model
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? NrDay{ get; set; }
    public int? NrMonth { get; set; }
    public int? NrYear{ get; set; }
    public string? Rozpoczecie { get; set; } 
    public string? Zakonczenie{ get; set; } 
    public string? OdbiorGodzin{ get; set; } 
    ...
}

public partial class ParentView
{
    public List<Karta_Model> Model1 { get; set; }
}
```

***View:***

```
using AppEcp.Models
@model ParentView

 @for (int nr_rows = 0; nr_rows < @ViewBag.daysInMonth; nr_rows++)
{
  <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].Rozpoczecie, new { @class = "start", @type = "time" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].Zakonczenie, new { @class = "end", @type = "time" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].OdbiorGodzin, new { @class = "gethours", @type = "time" })</td>
  </tr>
}
```

**Questions:**

- Is there any other way to send this data from the controller to the view?
- What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: **it throws me an error if it adds 'card' near the returned view**: Where does be code in your controller?

Comment: @Phong update, please guide me because I have been suffering from it for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `List<Karta>` while in View is expecting `ParentView`.

So you should do this

```
var karta = _ecpContext.Karta.Where(f => f.Miesiac == numerMiesiaca && f.Rok == numerRoku && f.Login == userName).OrderBy(x => x.Rok).ThenBy(x => x.Miesiac).ThenBy(x => x.DzMiesiaca).ToList();
var kartaModel = karta.Select(p => new Karta_Model 
               { 
                 Id = p.Id // Assign the rest of properties here 
               }).ToList();
var viewModel = new ParentView { Model1  = kartaModel  };

return PartialView("_ReturnView", viewModel);
```